# register_sidebar and white screen error

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I need to register a sidebar for a theme.
I've added this code to end of functions.php

```
<?php
include("widget.php");
 function farad_widgets_init(){
register_sidebar(array(
         'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'name' =>  'left-sidebar',
        'description' =>  'farad' ,
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'farad_widgets_init' ); 
?>
```

After I've added the code, wp-login.php show me a white screen.

What's the problem?

Comment: Possibly an error not being shown. Have you tried turning on error reporting?

Comment: The link is not accessible. You should include the errors in your post.

Comment: I have no problem in local host. but in main server i faced to these errors.

Comment: This could the result of a different PHP version or configuration. Compare the two between the development and production server.

Comment: I found with the latest version of xammp that errors aren't displayed. Best is to install some kind of debugging plugin, as for some reason the build in debug from wordpress doesn't work

Comment: local host: 5.5.9 and main server: 5.2.17

Comment: thanks, i'm not familiar with debug plugin. can you recommend any kind of it?

Comment: @user3087607 5.2.17 is quite an old version. If possible, consider updating it. Otherwise, read about the various backwards compatibility issues with that version.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the opening and closing php (`<?php ?>`) tags. You have most probably not closed your php tag after the last function, so adding your code as is, you creating a syntax error as you have an opening php tag within an already open php tag

Also, remove the `include()` part, it is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in function.php you will get left sidebar.

```php
function farad_widgets_init(){
register_sidebar(array(
         'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'name' =>  'left-sidebar',
        'description' =>  'farad' ,
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'farad_widgets_init' );
```